# How To Consume an API From a Nodemcu (ESP8266 WiFi Module)

Tags: kubernetes, nodemcu, micropython, kind, metallb

I have configured a Kubernetes kind cluster to run a flask API. The flask App when run locally with `flask run` produces an IP which is the local machine assigned IP from the local network `(192.168.100.19)`. My Nodemcu which also has an IP of `(192.168.100.36)` can talk to the Flask API.

However, things are different when I run the Flask app from the kind cluster. The kind nodes are in the network of `192.168.64.1` so my nodes' IPs are in that range. I used metallb to create the IP pools in that range as well so my Flask API is given a Loadbalancer IP of `192.168.63.200` This Flask API IP cannot be communicated with the Nodemcu IP of `192.168.100.36`

I know this is all about networking and things. This is what I've tried and and none work

- ExtraPortMappings to bind the running container port to the local machine IP. In some instances, I changed the listenAddress to 0.0.0.0

```yaml
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
name: iot-cluster05
nodes:
 * role: control-plane
  kubeadmConfigPatches:
 * |
    kind: InitConfiguration
    nodeRegistration:
      kubeletExtraArgs:
        node-labels: "ingress-ready=true"    
  extraPortMappings:
 * containerPort: 80
    hostPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
 * containerPort: 443
    hostPort: 443
    protocol: TCP
 * containerPort: 5000
    hostPort: 5000
    protocol: TCP
    listenAddress: "192.168.100.19"
```

- Hardcode the local machine IP as the node-ip

```yaml
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
name: iot-cluster01
nodes:
- role: control-plane
  extraPortMappings:
  - containerPort: 30000
    hostPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
  kubeadmConfigPatches:
  - |
    kind: InitConfiguration
    nodeRegistration:
      kubeletExtraArgs:
        node-ip: "192.168.100.19"
        cluster-dns: "192.168.100.1"
  - |
    kind: ClusterConfiguration
    apiServer:
      extraArgs:
        advertise-address: "192.168.100.19"
        bind-address: "0.0.0.0"
    controllerManager:
      extraArgs:
        bind-address: "0.0.0.0"
        node-cidr-mask-size: "24"
        allocate-node-cidrs: "true"
        cluster-cidr: "10.244.0.0/16"
containerdConfigPatches:
- | 
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.runc.options]
    SystemdCgroup = true
```

Settings Details

- Metallb version 0.13.7
- Kind v0.18.0
- Docker v23.0.1